# Replacing particuar String using xsl

Tags: xslt

I have a  block as below.

```
<rightOperand>.*ifIndedx.*</rightOperand>
```

But i need to change the above snippet to the below one

```
<rightOperand>(?i)(?s).*ifIndex.*</rightOperand>
```

This translation needs to be done only when the right operand starts and ends with the string `.*`

please provide me some pointers .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this my overriding the identity transform with an extra template just to match the text within **rightOperand** that matches your criteria

```
<xsl:template match="rightOperand/text()
 [starts-with(., '.*')]
 [substring(., string-length(.) - 1, 2) = '.*']">
```

Note that XSLT 1.0 does not have the **ends-with** function, which is why there is the extra work to check the ending with **substring**. If you were using XSLT 2.0 you could simplify this with **ends_with** though.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="rightOperand/text()
   [starts-with(., '.*')]
   [substring(., string-length(.) - 1, 2) = '.*']">
      <xsl:text>(?i)(?s)</xsl:text><xsl:copy />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<rightOperand>(?i)(?s).*ifIndedx.*</rightOperand>
```